# Msal.js not authenticating with google - Redirect uri issue

Tags: azure, authentication, google-authentication, google-developers-console, msal.js

So I recently used the quickstart method from Azure to make a JS app which authenticates using the MSAL.js library. I am able to authenticate using the normal users in AD, however when adding in google as an external identity provider, I get the Authorization error:
*"Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, [https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant-id}/oauth2/authresp](https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/%7Btenant-id%7D/oauth2/authresp), does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client...."*

I have checked the URI in my JS app, on Azure and added it in the Google develops console to no avail. I have followed the documentation as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google

I have tried fiddling with everything and don't know what to do to fix it. Keep in mind that when I created the Azure account, it automatically made my tenant name "Default directory" and my Primary domain as "{FirstName}{EmailDomain}@onmicrosoft.com". I since then change my tenant name to "NewTenant" (I will be changing all names for the purpose of this question as I would like to not reveal any actual details where possible).

To conceal my details I'll be making "{FirstName}": "Bob",  and "{EmailDomain}": "mydomain"

**JS code:**

```
      const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
          clientId: '{ClientId}', 
          authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}',
          domain: 'bobmydomain.onmicrosoft.com',
          instance: 'https://bobmydomain.b2clogin.com/tfp',
          redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/"
        },
        cache: {
          cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
          storeAuthStateInCookie: false
        }
      };
```

**Azure:**
[Azure redirect URIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6D30.png)

**Google developer console:**
[Google redirect URIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNFBK.png) Bear in mind I fiddled with the HTML so that I could get a nice screenshot. I have also configured the ClientID and ClientSecret for Google auth in the Azure external identity provider portal.
**EDIT: http://localhost:3000/ was also added as a redirect URI to the Google dev console but also to no avail**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the urls (exactly as registered) in azure b2c and the URLs your application is redirecting?

Comment: The last time I was working with B2C was some string concatenation made by MSAL that made me crazy

Comment: Hi @Ricardo. I can post the exact urls if need be but they follow the EXACT same structure as shown in the images above. However if this still does not suffice, I will post the URLs. Also how do i see the URL the application is redirecting? Do you mean the one that comes in Google Error message?

Comment: In Google's chrome developer tools, go to network tab, enable 'preserve log' to see all the urls redirected.

Comment: I think you're going to find the answer yourself, but if not post the urls here.